# Message queue considerations - MSMQ storage issue kills current app

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I am working on two apps that use an MSMQ as a message bus mechanism so that A transfers messages to B. This clearly has to be robust so initially we chose MSMQ to store and transfer the messages.

When testing the app we noticed that in real-world conditions, where msmq is called to handle approximately 50.000 messages a minute (which sounds quite low to me) then we quickly reach the max storage size of the msmq /storage directory (defaults to 1.2gb i think).

We can increase that but I was wondering whether there is a better approach to handle slow receivers and fast senders. Is there a better queue or a better approach to use in this case?

Actually it isnt so much a problem of slow receivers since msmq will maintain the (received) messages in the storage dir for something like 6 hours or until the service is restarted. So essentially if in 5 minutes we reach the 1gb threshold then in a few hours we will reach terratybes of data!

Comment: You are an order of magnitude beyond what you can reasonably expect out of msmq transactional queues.  That requires a redesign, not a bandaid.

Comment: If the messages disappear after 6 hours then you have set a TimeToBeReceived of 6 hours. If the messages disappear after a restart then you are using EXPRESS messages and that is to be expected - you do NOT have a robust system and should be using transactional or recoverable messages. One way to handle slow receivers is throttling - set a quota on the queue so that the sender gets bounced; sender can be designed to resend until the queue volume has reduced below the quota. There is no maximum storage size for MSMQ (see my answer below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/insufficient-resources-run-away-run-away.aspx) to understand how MSMQ uses resources which I put together after years of supporting MSMQ at Microsoft.
It really does cover all the areas you need to know about.
If you have heard something about MSMQ that isn't in the blog then it is alomost certainly wrong - such as the 1.2GB storage limit for MSMQ. The maximum size of the msmq\storage directory is the hard disk capacity - it's an NTFS folder!
You should be able to have a queue with millions of messages in it (assuming you have enough kernel memory, as mentioned in the blog)

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: the 1.6 limit comes from this kb article http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;899613 of the error i got in the app when i googled it.

Comment: That KB article is for Windows 2000 (MSMQ 2.0) and is discussed as item 3 of my blog. The limit was removed in 2002 with Windows XP (MSMQ 3.0). Ideally the KB article would be archived/deleted.

Comment: Coincidentally when the app crashed i checked the /storage folder and it was around 1-1.2 gb of messages there. 

Comment: The pattern-matching ability of the human mind is both an asset and a hindrance. :-)
Expect you are running out of kernel memory to index the huge number of messages with. Number of messages is more important than volume of messages.

Comment: Also, you talk about the application crashing or being killed. What exactly happens?

Comment: I get the insufficient resources message as you say in the blog. the machine is a windows server 2008 standard. I basically want the message to be removed when one consumer retrieves it. currently i can see that messages remain on disk and the app crashes when the messages on disk is at around 1.0-1.5 gb. consider that each message is approx 100kb so messages are quite large

Comment: I repeat: "Number of messages is more important than volume of messages." 100kb messages are not large. The only message size you need to worry about is 4 megabytes - anything smaller will be fine. In your case, I would guess you have a maximum of around 10,000 messages if they average 100kb each. As you have "insufficient resources" errors then work through the blog, as recommended yesterday, especially item 4.

Answer (score 4):

You should apply an SLA to your subscribers, they have to read their messages with in X amount of time or they lose them. You can scale this SLA to match the volume of messages that arrive.

For subscribers that cannot meet their SLA then simply put, they don't really care about receiving their messages that quickly (if they did, they would be available). For these subscribers you can offer a slower channel, such as an XML dump of the messages in the last hour (or what ever granularity is required). You probably wouldn't store each individual message here, but just an aggregate of changes (eg, something that can be queried from a DB).

---

Use separate queues for each message type, this way you can apply different priorities depending on the importance of the message, if one queue becomes full, messages of other types won't be blocked. It also makes it simpler to monitor if each message is being processed within its SLA by looking at the first message in the queue and seeing when it was added to determine how long it was waiting (see NServiceBus).

---

From your above metrics of 1GB in 5 minutes at 50,000 messages/minute I calculate each message to be about 4kb. This is quite large for a message since messages should normally only be carrying top level details about something happening, mostly IDs of what was changed, and the intent of what was changed. Larger data is better served from some other out-of-band channel for transferring large blobs (eg, file share, sftp, etc).

Also, since a service should encapsulate its own data, you shouldn't need to share much data between services. So large data within a service using messages to say what happened isn't unusual, large data between separate services using messages indicates that some boundaries are probably leaking.